# iterate thru dict ordered by descending summed values

Tags: python

My dictionary looks like this...

```
   d = {'clovato': [2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0], 'fnegro': [1.0, 3.0, 0.5], 'jbgood': [4.0, 4.0, 1.5, 1.5]}
```

So while I can calculate the sum of each key's value

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print(k,sum(v))

clovato 7.5
fnegro 4.5
jbgood 11.0
```

What I really need is to have the key-value pairs print in descending order of the sum. In this case, I want the output to be:

```
jbgood, [4.0, 4.0, 1.5, 1.5]
clovato, [2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
fnegro, [1.0, 3.0, 0.5]
```

Comment: (1) Convert dictionary to a list of key-value pairs. (2) Sort it using the sum as key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `sorted` and use the `sum` as the key, using `reverse` to make it ascending.

```
d = {'clovato': [2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0], 'fnegro': [1.0, 3.0, 0.5], 'jbgood': [4.0, 4.0, 1.5, 1.5]}

od = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: sum(x[1]),reverse=True)

for key,value in od:
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using comprehension with sorted `x[0]` and reverse

```
print(*sorted([[k, v] for k, v in d.items()], key=lambda x: sum(x[1]), reverse = True))
```

> ```
> ['jbgood', [4.0, 4.0, 1.5, 1.5]] ['clovato', [2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]] ['fnegro', [1.0, 3.0, 0.5]]
> ```